# Need to create a lambda function in Ohio region but the Jar is available in S3 Bucket of Virgina Region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

How to access the S3bucket from Virgina region and upload the jar file to lambda function in ohio region.

Comment: Mark can you help on this

Comment: Are you saying that the JAR file used for the Lambda function is in a different region to your Lambda function? Or are you saying that the Lambda function in one region wants to access an object in an S3 bucket in a different region, but this object is _not_ used to run the Lambda function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [aws blog post from 2019](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/infrastructure-and-automation/deploying-aws-lambda-functions-using-aws-cloudformation-the-portable-way/) indicates that "Lambda requires the bucket to reside in the same AWS Region as the function".  It has some recommendation on how you might work around that limitation with custom resources to automatically replicates lambda zips from one bucket/region into others.